# Weird JSON like notation. What language is this?

Tags: javascript, json, notation

I just stumbled across this weird JSON like notation that's being returned by a certain server at work. It has a lot in common with JSON, but I can't parse it using javascripts `JSON.parse()` function. The notation is as follows:

```
[
  {
    :key value,
    :someRandomKey "This is a string value",
    :someOtherKey true
  }
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

Notice the lack of quotes, the strange key notation after the double dots, the lack of comma's between objects. Does anyone know what language / notation this could be?

Comment: What does the `Content-Type` header of the server response say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notation is found in Clojure see link: [clojure](https://clojure.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Ruby code to me. The notation shown is called Ruby symbols most likely.

Comment: If this where Ruby it's missing the arrow. `{ :key => "value" }` and `{ key: "value" }` are both valid, `{ :key "value" }` isn't.

Comment: It's looks like Ruby, but like @3limin4t0r said, it's missing some key parts. The content-type can't help, since this is returned as a sting, that's part of a bigger valid JSON structure

Comment: @NotBramKorsten Have you checked the API documentation? Maybe it describes what the value is supposed to be.

Comment: @3limin4t0r No luck there, sorry. I'll let you know when I find out more!